# Imagem fica visivel antes do Animate.css e wow.js carregarem

Tags: css, animate.css, wow.js

Tenho algumas animações usando `animate.css` e `wow.js`, coloquei alguns delay pelo wow, mas assim que o site carrega as imagens já são mostradas e depois aplica a animação, não quero que elas apareçam antes da animação, se tiver delay de 10s quero que a imagem que esta o efeito não apareça e só apareça qdo fazer a animação, acredito que já teria que ser assim pelo wow, mas como faço um codigo para que a imagem fica com opacity 0 e depois com a animação ele passar pra 1, ou algo do tipo que resolva isso?

Comment: Não consegue criar um fiddle?

Comment: Não sei o que é isso kkkk, vou ver no Google

Comment: posta o código aqui

Comment: @LennonS.Bueno são várias animações o código é grande, se entende de animate.css e wow.css sabe do que estou falando, não tem como colocar os códigos dessas bibliotecas aqui. Esse é meu logo que tem a animação `<img class="img-responsive logo wow fadeIn" data-wow-delay="2s" src="imagens/logo.png">` Como pode ver esta com delay de 2s, mas não quero que a imagem apareça antes desses 2s, quero que ela só apareça com o efeito fadeIn, mas assim que o site carrega ela ja aparece e depois ela some e vem o efeito fadeIn, quero que ela fique oculta até o efeito surgir.

Comment: Blz @GuilhermeNascimento obrigado pela ajuda mas não conheço e dei uma pesquisada e vai me complicar mais ainda, vou ter que aprender isso pra poder explicar o que eu quero. Eu preciso apenas de um codigo em js que esconda o elemento por 2s, esse esconda pode ser uma classe com display none ou opacity 0, ou que "esconda" até que a classe fadein do animate aja sobre o elemento. Vou continuar pesquisando aqui pra ver como faço isso. Obrigado pela ajuda.

Comment: Isso é estranho, eu acho que ou a classe `img-responsive` ou a classe `logo` ou outro CSS está conflitando com o animate.css, se você puder enviar um link talvez ajude. PS: me responde outra coisa, quando vc fala `wow css` na verdade você quer dizer `WOW.js` né? Porque wow.css eu não conheço.

Comment: Sim é wow.js a classe img-responsive do bootstrap já retirei ela e a .logo é a que eu criei, não tem nada conflitando, veja `.logo {
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    top: 5%;
    z-index: 3;
}`

Comment: Mas então pelo vc quis dizer já era pra não aparecer as imagens antes de as animações ocorrerem? Mesmo sem eu criar codigo pra isso? As bibliotecas animate.css e wow.js já teriam essa propriedade? Pq pelo que pesquisei é isso msm

Comment: mano não to falando para postar a biblioteca, e sim o seu código JS e HTML, quando você entra na comunidade é demonstrado como realizar perguntas, se você pulou essa parte recomendo fortemente iniciar novamente,  ajude a ser ajudado.

Comment: Já tem uma pessoa que conhece animate.css e wow.js e sabe que é impossivel colocar o js aqui, ele esta me ajudando, muito obrigado.

Comment: @ClaytonFurlanetto sei que é iniciante, mas agora observando a resposta do nosso amigo introduza o mínimo de código possível nas proximas perguntas, ah e a lib ele adicionou via cdn..

Comment: Consegui identificar o erro e já resolvi.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Como você não postou o código não tem como saber aonde você errou, então me arriscando você chutar algumas hipóteses:

### Você esqueceu do new WOW().init();

O `new WOW().init();` deve ir no final da página, depois de tudo de preferencia, veja como funcionou corretamente:

```html
<link href="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/animate.css/3.5.2/animate.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/wow/1.1.2/wow.min.js"></script>

<br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>
<br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>
<hr>

<img 
 class="wow fadeIn"
 data-wow-duration="2s"
 data-wow-delay="2s"
 src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/YCSmc.jpg?s=328&g=1">

<script>
new WOW().init();
</script>
```

### Conflito com outros CSS como Bootstrap

Pode ser que a classe `.img-response` ou `.logo` esteja afetando o `opacity:` não posso afirmar, mas de qualquer forma experimente remove-los temporariamente (isso citei como exemplo, pode ser que até mesmo um CSS que não seja uma classe esteja afetando)

### Tempo de download

Pode ser que por algum motivo que só olhando para o seu HTML para saber, você tenha feito o CSS sem haver o bloqueio de renderização, o que você pode tentar usar para contornar isto seria simplesmente usar a tag `style` dentro de `head` com isto:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>

...

<style>
.wow {
    opacity: 0;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
...
```

> Os `...` são apenas ilustrativos, para dizer que existe mais código ali

Desta maneira todos elementos com a classe `wow` irão começar de maneira forçada com `opacity: 0`

Comment: As classes estão corretas e o `new WOW().init();` tbm esta inserido no lugar correto, as bibliotecas estão funcionando, os efeitos estão ocorrendo, só que as imagens que deveriam ficar "escondidas" e só aparecer qdo a animação ocorrer, isso não esta funcionando, e vc disse sobre o `opacity:` não sei qual é, já que essa é minha dúvida desde o começo, criar uma função com um opacity o antes da animação iniciar e uma com opacity 1 qdo a animação ocorrer.

Comment: @ClaytonFurlanetto vc quer dizer que elas estão carregando ou que elas estão visiveis? Porque uma coisa é fazer o "download" outra coisa é efeito de transição. Você quer que a imagem somente baixe quando ela entrar no viewport (após o scroll)?

Comment: Eu coloquei o efeito pra ocorrer após 2s, ai o site carrega e já aparece a imagem e depois dos 2s a imagem some e entra com o efeito de FadeIn. Eu não quero que ela já apareça qdo carregar o site, ela só tem que aparecer qdo entrar o fadeIn, alguns outros efeitos estão corretos mas tem algumas imagens que estão assim, e não vejo nada de errado, por isso pensei em criar alguma função e js pra nao mostrar a imagem antes do fadein.

Comment: @ClaytonFurlanetto tente adicionar isso dentro de HEAD `<style>.wow { opacity:0; }</style>`

Comment: Agora colocando isso que vc disse, todos os elementos que estao com a classe wow nao apareceram ao carregar o site mas apareceram no inicio da animação e após animar sumiram, não sei se sabe mas a classo wow apenas controla os delay e a duração e a classe dos efeitos tipo fadein fadeout que controla a animação. Agora ja vou embora e vou ver se amanha descubro esse misterio kkk, qq coisa aviso aqui. Muito obrigado pela ajuda irmão vlw msm.

Comment: @ClaytonFurlanetto entendi, se vc puder me mandar o link de vosso website online via inbox no face ou via email para brcontainer@yahoo.com.br eu posso olhar pra isto com mais detalhes e chegar a fonte do problema.

Comment: Vou colocar o site no ar e te mando no face o link